# What is wrong with this expression in Java?

Tags: java, string, concatenation

I want to make an expression that would if put into code print the first char of first then a period followed by the first char of second and so on till third.

```
first.substring(0, 1) + "." + second.substring(0, 1) + "." + third.substring(0, 1)
```

Comment: What is the output that you are getting currently? Sample outputs will help as well.

Comment: For one, there's no semi-colon at the end.

Comment: I'm doing an online exercise that wants fragment code, all that it's telling me is that this is the wrong way to accomplish the task...

Comment: @SalRosa what is the actual task ?

Comment: It probably wants you to use `charAt` instead?

Comment: using string concatenation print the first char of first followed by a period, then the first char of second followed by a period, then the first char of third followed by a period. So if first=guy, second=person, third=thing it would print g.p.t

Comment: Turns out I needed a third "." thank you guys though.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the charAt method.

first.charAt(0) should return the first character in first.

Or first, second, and third might not be defined in the context, be sure that you are using the same variable names and casing for them as the website expects.

Comment: I got it to work turns out i need three ".", Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

> using string concatenation print the first char of first followed by a
>   period, then the first char of second followed by a period, then the
>   first char of third followed by a period. So if first=guy,
>   second=person, third=thing it would print g.p.t

```
first.charAt(0)+"."+second.charAt(0)+"."+third.charAt(0);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `charAt(0)`??